# How to keep not change when resize the font size?

Tags: html, css

Here is my css and html code

```css
.navi ul li {
  float:left;
  list-style-type: none;
  border-right: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
  margin:0px 0 0 0;
}

.navi ul li:last-child {
  border:none;
}

.navi ul li a {
  display:block;
  margin:0 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color:black;
}

#info {
  display:block;
  margin:0px 20px 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size:80%;
  color:gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="navi">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">MANUALS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">NEWS</a></li>
    <li><a href="">SPARE PART</a></li>
    <li><a href="">WHERE TO BUY</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">SUPPORT</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">EDIT BOOK</a></li>
    <li><span id="info">Hi, Guest</span></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="login">LOG IN</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I need to resize the font of li item but I found out that the border will also change to the one I just resize the font.

What can I do to keep right border of "Hi, Guest" same size as others when I try to resize the font size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove `display:block` from `#info` as below

```
#info {     
  margin:0px 20px 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size:80%;
  color:gray;
}
```

**Snippet**

```css
.navi ul li {
  float:left;
  list-style-type: none;
  border-right: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
  margin:0px 0 0 0;
}

.navi ul li:last-child {
  border:none;
}

.navi ul li a {
  display:block;
  margin:0 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color:black;
}

#info {
 
  margin:0px 20px 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size:80%;
  color:gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="navi">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">MANUALS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">NEWS</a></li>
    <li><a href="">SPARE PART</a></li>
    <li><a href="">WHERE TO BUY</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">SUPPORT</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">EDIT BOOK</a></li>
    <li><span id="info">Hi, Guest</span></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="login">LOG IN</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `line-height: 20px` for the list item

```css
.navi ul li {
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
  border-right: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
  margin: 0px 0 0 0;
  line-height: 20px; // Add
}
.navi ul li:last-child {
  border: none;
}
.navi ul li a {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
#info {
  display: block;
  margin: 0px 20px 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 80%;
  color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="navi">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">MANUALS</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">NEWS</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">SPARE PART</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">WHERE TO BUY</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">SUPPORT</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">EDIT BOOK</a>
    </li>
    <li><span id="info">Hi, Guest</span>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" id="login">LOG IN</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For things like this **ALWAYS** post a fiddle.

If you mean that the element expands with the font size, that is default behavior of html/css.

You can either set fixed height of an element or make the text position:absolute in order to not expand its parents size

Comment: Sorry. So i can just po fiddle link here??

Comment: Thanks. I thought just post a link then ask is not allow here XD

Comment: You can include link in your question.

Comment: Fiddle not required. StackOverflow has provided facility of Snippets. They work best for normal HTML , CSS and jQuery

Comment: @captainsac I found the local fiddles very hard to work with, so I still prefer external fiddles

Comment: Check this link http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: @captainsac Oh I know how it works, I just dont find it easy/user-friendly to work with. Until it improves, I prefer to use external fiddle.